# How To Dynamically add Dropdown buttons or delete dropdown(s) in listview with flutter Web?

Tags: flutter

i have created a page where a user who will click a title to edit the contents and can add and delete devices that the article is attached to,

but i could not figure it out on how to program the drop down dynamically, to add more drop downs when a user press the add device button,

the additional function they want me to add as well is on the Dropdown list, when they select 'NONE' it should remove that dropdown as well,

i am planning to use mysql,xampp or sqlite for my database if im done with the UI,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:surveyadminpanel/Contents/tabbar.dart';
import 'package:surveyadminpanel/widgets/button.dart';
import 'package:surveyadminpanel/widgets/simplewidgets.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

class Item {
  Item(this.name);
  String name;
}

class editsurvey extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _editsurveyState createState() => _editsurveyState();
}

class _editsurveyState extends State<editsurvey>{

  int surveyquestionnum = 1;
  int surveyquestiontotal = 1;

  List<Item> selectedUser = [null, null];
  List<Item> selecteddata = [null, null];
  List<Item> users;


  int linkdevices = 1;
  String dropdownvalue= "SELECT FROM DROPDOWN";
  List data = [
    'Sample Data 1',
    'Sample Data 2',
    'Sample Data 3',
    'Sample Data 4',
    'Sample Data 5',
    'Sample Data 6',
  ];




  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    users = <Item>[
      Item('Sample device 1'),
      Item('Sample device 2'),
      Item('Sample device 3'),
      Item('Sample device 4'),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget _dropdownbutton (List<Item> userlist, int index){
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(15.0) //
        ),
      ),
      child: DropdownButton<Item>(
        underline: SizedBox(),
        isExpanded: true,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        hint:  Text("  $dropdownvalue"),
        value: selectedUser[index],
        onChanged: (Item Value) {
          setState(() {
            selectedUser[index] = Value;
          });
        },
        items: userlist.map((Item user) {
          return  DropdownMenuItem<Item>(
            value: user,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(width: 10,),
                Text(
                  user.name,
                  style:  TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget _text(texthere,bold,size,color){
    return Text(texthere,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: bold,fontSize: size,color: color),overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,maxLines: 1);
  }
  Widget _logo(){
    return InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => admincontent()),
          );
        },
        child: Container(width: 500,height: 200,child: Image.asset("images/v2.jpg")));
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: 'Good Morning Welcome to Sample:',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 18),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(text: usernametitle,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                    )
                  ]
              ),
            )
        ),
        elevation: 1,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: _logo(),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            tooltip: 'Show Notification',
            onPressed: () {
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            color: Colors.lightGreen,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            tooltip: 'Check your Profile',
            onPressed: () {
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 5),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _text("EDIT SURVEY", FontWeight.bold, 20,Colors.blue),
                  roundedRectButton("BACK", signInGradients),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      width: screenWidth/1.6,
                      height: screenHeight/1.6,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.orange[200],
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            _text("SURVEY TITLE", FontWeight.bold, 17,Colors.white),
                            _text(data[0], FontWeight.bold, 19, Colors.black),
                            _text("DATE CREATED", FontWeight.bold, 17,Colors.white),
                            _text(data[1], null, 19, Colors.black),
                            _text("CURRENT STATUS", FontWeight.bold, 17,Colors.white),
                            _text(data[2], null, 19, Colors.black),
                            _text("LANGUAGE VERSION", FontWeight.bold, 17,Colors.white),
                            _text(data[3], null, 19, Colors.black),
                            _text("NUMBERS OF ASSESSORS", FontWeight.bold, 17,Colors.white),
                            _text(data[4], null, 19, Colors.black),
                            _text("TOTAL RENDERED SURVEYS", FontWeight.bold, 17,Colors.white),
                            _text(data[5], null, 19, Colors.black),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: (){

                                  },
                                  child: Container(width: 100,height: 50,child: Text("EDIT SURVEY")),
                                ),
                                _text("LINKED DEVICES : $linkdevices", FontWeight.bold, 17,Colors.white),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            width: 1.0,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid
                        )
                    ),
                    width: screenWidth/1.6,
                    height: screenHeight/1.6,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _text("DEVICES PINNED", FontWeight.bold, 20,Colors.blue),
                        ListView.separated(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: linkdevices,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index){
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: _dropdownbutton(users, index),
                              );
                            },
                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(height: 10),
                            ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            InkWell(
                              child: roundedRectButton("ADD DEVICE", signInGradients),
                              onTap: (){

                              },
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              child: roundedRectButton("CLEAR ALL DEVICE", signInGradients),
                              onTap: (){

                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**The Plan** 
[image]

**The Result**
[image]

im still trying to figure this out, but if someone can give me a lift,, im gonna be very thankful to who can help me out here ,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can increase `linkdevices` and `selectedUser`

code snippet

```
List<Item> selectedUser = [null];
...
InkWell(
          child: Text("ADD DEVICE"),
          onTap: () {
            selectedUser.add(null);
            linkdevices ++;
            setState(() {

            });
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Item {
  Item(this.name);
  String name;
}

class editsurvey extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _editsurveyState createState() => _editsurveyState();
}

class _editsurveyState extends State<editsurvey> {
  int surveyquestionnum = 1;
  int surveyquestiontotal = 1;

  List<Item> selectedUser = [null];
  List<Item> selecteddata = [null, null];
  List<Item> users;

  int linkdevices = 1;
  String dropdownvalue = "SELECT FROM DROPDOWN";
  List data = [
    'Sample Data 1',
    'Sample Data 2',
    'Sample Data 3',
    'Sample Data 4',
    'Sample Data 5',
    'Sample Data 6',
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    users = <Item>[
      Item('Sample device 1'),
      Item('Sample device 2'),
      Item('Sample device 3'),
      Item('Sample device 4'),
    ];

  }

  @override
  Widget _dropdownbutton(List<Item> userlist, int index) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0) //
            ),
      ),
      child: DropdownButton<Item>(
        underline: SizedBox(),
        isExpanded: true,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        hint: Text("  $dropdownvalue"),
        value: selectedUser[index],
        onChanged: (Item Value) {
          print(Value.toString());
          print(index);
          setState(() {
            selectedUser[index] = Value;
          });
        },
        items: userlist.map((Item user) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<Item>(
            value: user,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  user.name,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _text(texthere, bold, size, color) {
    return Text(texthere,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: bold, fontSize: size, color: color),
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        maxLines: 1);
  }

  Widget _logo() {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => admincontent()),
          );
        },
        child: Container(
            width: 500, height: 200, child: Image.asset("images/v2.jpg")));
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  text: 'Good Morning Welcome to Sample:',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 18),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "usernametitle",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                    )
                  ]),
            )),
        elevation: 1,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: _logo(),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            tooltip: 'Show Notification',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            color: Colors.lightGreen,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            tooltip: 'Check your Profile',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 5),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _text("EDIT SURVEY", FontWeight.bold, 20.0, Colors.blue),
                  //roundedRectButton("BACK", signInGradients),
                  Text("BACK"),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      width: screenWidth / 1.6,
                      height: screenHeight / 1.6,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.orange[200],
                        borderRadius:
                            new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            _text("SURVEY TITLE", FontWeight.bold, 17.0,
                                Colors.white),
                            _text(data[0], FontWeight.bold, 19.0, Colors.black),
                            _text("DATE CREATED", FontWeight.bold, 17.0,
                                Colors.white),
                            _text(data[1], null, 19.0, Colors.black),
                            _text("CURRENT STATUS", FontWeight.bold, 17.0,
                                Colors.white),
                            _text(data[2], null, 19.0, Colors.black),
                            _text("LANGUAGE VERSION", FontWeight.bold, 17.0,
                                Colors.white),
                            _text(data[3], null, 19.0, Colors.black),
                            _text("NUMBERS OF ASSESSORS", FontWeight.bold, 17.0,
                                Colors.white),
                            _text(data[4], null, 19.0, Colors.black),
                            _text("TOTAL RENDERED SURVEYS", FontWeight.bold,
                                17.0, Colors.white),
                            _text(data[5], null, 19.0, Colors.black),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  child: Container(
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 50,
                                      child: Text("EDIT SURVEY")),
                                ),
                                _text("LINKED DEVICES : $linkdevices",
                                    FontWeight.bold, 17.0, Colors.white),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            width: 1.0,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                    width: screenWidth / 1.6,
                    height: screenHeight / 1.6,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _text("DEVICES PINNED", FontWeight.bold, 20.0,
                            Colors.blue),
                        ListView.separated(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: linkdevices,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: _dropdownbutton(users, index),
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(height: 10),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            InkWell(
                              child: Text("ADD DEVICE"),
                              onTap: () {
                                selectedUser.add(null);
                                linkdevices ++;
                                setState(() {

                                });
                                /*listWidget.add(  ListView.separated(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: linkdevices,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: _dropdownbutton(users, index),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(height: 10),
                                ));
                                setState(() {

                                });*/
                              },
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              child: Text("CLEAR ALL DEVICE"),
                              onTap: () {},
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class admincontent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: editsurvey(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this works,, although can you give me just a simple explenation how ?and what was changed?

Comment: one last request,, how can i have the left side to be fixed on its position? and the right side once it goes more than 20 devices it will just turn in to a scrollable one,.,, cause i just reaalized my code somehow drags the left one to the bottom once it goes multiple devices and there is an overflow cant press the button bellow

Comment: you can see code snippet. add linkdevices let listview auto add new dropdown button